# Determine the resource usage before running BigQuery job

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery, google-sheets-api

I've Integrated Big Query with Google Sheets successfully.
As I'm using dynamic parameters to decide on the nature of the query (for example, timeframe), I would like to understand the "cost" of the query - how much MB (or KB or GB) will it take to run.

Any way for such an indication *before* running the query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use the dryRun flag. The server will tell you the amount it will process

```
{
  "configuration": {
    "query": {
      "query": "SELECT SUM(a.field) FROM `project.dataset.table`",
      "useLegacySql": false
    },
    "dryRun": true
  }
}
```

You need to evaluate the statistics infos provided:

```
...
 "statistics": {
 "creationTime": "1526584760494",
  "totalBytesProcessed": "152193056",
  "query": {
   "totalBytesProcessed": "152193056",
   "totalBytesBilled": "0",
   "cacheHit": false,
...
```

As you can see no bytes were billed.
You can try it out here before implementing:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/insert

There are no real spreadsheet specifics to this, since AppsScript also uses the API.